# Поиск в структуре

Tags: c++builder, структуры

Не так выводится, как надо. Тут надо вывести имя (ена) только тех (того), у кого возраст превышает 25 лет, а  компилятор не так выводит...

```
void search_age(person * mas, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (mas[i].age > 25) {
            cout << mas[i].name << endl;
        } else
            cout << "Sotrudnik(i) s takimi kriteriyami ne nayden(i)";
}
```

Comment: Вы сначала всех распечатайте. Вдруг не тот массив в search_age() передаете.

Comment: в дополнение к первому комментарию проверьте что у вас n > 0

Comment: Не, если он какой-то вывод видит (он пишет, что *не так выводит*), значит n > 0.

Comment: да я уже распечатывал, он выводит у меня имена все не завися от того что условие стоит mas[i]>25, и то что таких сотрудников нет тоже выводит, что тут изменить можно? или как записать?

Comment: В отдельном цикле в самом начале функции распечатайте все имена **вместе** с возрастом.

В обновлении своего вопроса опубликуйте результат.

Answer (score 1):

Чудес в программровании не бывает, поэтому у Вас где-то ошибка, таким образом самый очевидный способ найти её - это запустить Вашу программу в дебаггере и поставить брэкпоинт там где у вас **if**  и проследить как программа выполняется и какие значения содержатся в **age** при сравнении.

У вас передается указатель в функцию, поэтому что бы проще было найти ошибку напишите, пожалуйста, то как Вы эту функцию вызываете и как у вас определена структура( или класс) **person**